# Trying to arrange five subfigures in three rows

Tags: subfloats

I want to place five subfigures into one figure. The first one is a wide rectangle. The other four are closer to squares. [[image: I want an arrangement like this]]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}

begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth, angle =90 ]{a}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth,cfbox=green 1pt 1pt]{b}\quad
\caption{b}
\label{b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth,cfbox=red 1pt 1pt]{c}
\caption{c}
\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[d]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,cfbox=green 1pt 1pt]{d}  
\caption{d}
\label{d}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[e]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,cfbox=red 1pt 1pt]{e}  
\caption{e}
\label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{blabla}

\end{minipage}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following example code can help get you started. Just replace the `filename` placholder with the actual file names, remove `[demo]` from the `graphicx` package, compile and see if it suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the demo option in your actual document!

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
\caption{}
\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
\caption{}
\label{b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
\caption{}
\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
\caption{}
\label{d}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{filename}
\caption{}
\label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{blabla}
\label{figurelabel}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```